# function and pass arguments

Tags: bash, arguments, bash-functions

So this is my first function:

```
#!/bin/bash

lets_print () {

    echo hello $1
}

lets_print Earth

lets_print Mars
```

## ready to show result

```
user@bash$ ./demo.sh

Hello Earth

Hello Mars
```

## And this is my 2nd function:

```
#!/bin/bash

lets_print () {

    echo hello $1 $2
}

lets_print Earth

lets_print Mars
```

## ready to show the second result:

```
user@bash$ ./demo.sh

Hello Earth

Hello Mars
```

Can someone please explain why they have the same result?

Right now I am thinking `$1=Earth` and `$2=Mars`. But I know this is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are showing the same result because you are only passing one positional parameter per function call.  In order for mars to be the second parameter you would need to call like this:

```
lets_print Earth Mars
```

Recommended reading on positional parameters: [3.4.1 Positional Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters)

Comment: @Denny If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Also, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo